# SignalR how to preserve message order from server to client

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr

I've got a problem that when I send messages from Server to client they don't arrive at the client in their original order. I've got a test function here:

```
public async Task Hello(string group)
    {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        await Clients.Group("grp1").Hello("grp1");
        await Clients.Group("grp2").Hello("grp2");
        await Clients.All.Hello("all");
    }
```

And on client:

```
var chanceHub = $.connection.chanceHub;
chanceHub.client.Hello = function (message) {
    alert(message);
}
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chanceHub.server.hello("grp1");
});
```

I expect to get 2 alerts in this order: "grp1" then "all"
But I always get the message "all" first.
Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: SignalR will preserve message order. Are you sure that the client is being added to the group?

Comment: @StephenCleary yes, the client is in grp1. But the order is not preserved and I can not understand why... the message order inside a group is ok, but when it comes to messaging between groups everything shuffles

Answer (score 5):

It's an unresolved issue #3310 for this problem. The issue also describes a workaround [Issue #3310](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3310)

Comment: That issue suggests adding `await`s to make things work. The OPs code already contains `await`.